# Laravel list of file names from ZIP archive, show in blade

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, php-ziparchive

I have little trouble to show names of files which are contains in ZIP archive in blade.

`blade controller`:

```
$zip_archive = new \ZipArchive(); 

    $zip_archive->open($fileName); 
    
    for( $i = 0; $i < $zip_archive->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
        $stat = $zip_archive->statIndex( $i ); 
        print_r( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL ); 
    }
```

`print_r` show in `blade` 1.png 2.png. 3.png 4.png

is possible to transform this to table ?

something like

```
@foreach ($ as $)
    <td>{{ }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method

```
    $zip_archive = new \ZipArchive(); 
    $zip_archive->open($fileName); 
    $filenames= [];
    if(!empty($zip_archive)){
       for($i = 0; $i < $zip_archive->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
            $stat = $zip_archive->statIndex( $i ); 
            // file's name
            $filenames[] = "{construct it}"; 
      }
    }
    return view('your_view',["filenames"=>$filenames]);
```

In your view

```
  @if(count($filenames) > 0) 
     @foreach($filenames as $filename)
       {{$filename}}
     @endforeach
   @endif
```

Comment: ````dd($filenames)```` show array wih all file names, perfectly. but what can be problem in blade ERROR: ````undefined variable:filenames```` in ````your_view.blade.php```` ?

Comment: with this change your solution working -> change this ````return view('your_view',  $filenames);```` to ````return view('your_view',["filenames"=>$filenames]);````